# Spring Data Redis Repository returning null for expired entries

Tags: java, spring, redis, spring-data

I'm using a `CrudRepository` for connecting to Redis in my Spring Boot application and a `@TimeToLive` annotated field in the entity for expiration:

```java
@RedisHash("keyspace")
public class MyRedisEntity {
    @Id String key;
    MyPojo pojo;
    @TimeToLive Long ttl;
}

public interface MyRedisRepository extends CrudRepository<MyRedisEntity, String>{}
```

Now when the expiration has taken place, `myRedisRepo.findAll()` returns null for the expired entities. I discovered redis (or spring-data redis) stores all inserted entities' id in a set with the keyspace as key:

```
redis-cli> smembers keyspace
0) key0
1) key1
2) key2
...
redis-cli> hgetall key0
(empty list or set)
```

I suspect this set is used for the `findAll` call, returning null for ids no longer present as hashmaps due to expiration. Also, I tried using a listener for `RedisKeyExpiredEvent`, using the repository's delete method in `onApplicationEvent`, but that doesn't help.

```java
@Component
public class RedisExpirationListener implements ApplicationListener<RedisKeyExpiredEvent> {

    private MyRedisRepository myRedisRepository;

    @Autowired
    public RedisExpirationListener(MyRedisRepository myRedisRepository) {
        this.myRedisRepository = myRedisRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(RedisKeyExpiredEvent redisKeyExpiredEvent) {
        if (redisKeyExpiredEvent.getKeyspace().equals("keyspace")) {
            myRedisRepository.deleteById(new String(redisKeyExpiredEvent.getId()));
        }
    }
}
```

What should I do to get only non null entries? Ideally I'd want the expired entries to be deleted entirely from redis and thus not appear in `findAll`, but it'd be sufficient if a repository method could return list of non null values.

(And yes, I know about the phantom behaviour, but I don't think it's relevant to what I want)

Comment: Hi @aksh1618, where you able to resolve this? What was your workaround? Saw this https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREDIS-570 but no fix yet

Comment: @Enoobong I had to resort to filtering everywhere I used `findAll`: `StreamSupport.stream(myRedisRepository.findAll().spliterator(), false).filter(Objects::nonNull)`

Comment: Ok thanks, me too 

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Enoobong there is open issue  https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREDIS-570 (and there is a **workaround** added this September)
It is open for 5 years.

That means you should use RedishHash with TTL very carefully:

- Make sure your Redis server allows your app to 'CONFIGURE' keyspace events
- Make sure you have a workaround from github issue

But that is still not recommended as production-ready solution (I mean configuring kayspace events from app annotation) so please consider putting this to the application logic to keep the scheduler to remove outdated records.
Also this meens you need to handle null values returned from the repo until that issue is fixed.